# can anyone identify the bug in this mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb

can anybody identify bug in following mongodb code. I need to collect two tables as much linke JOIN in mysql. BUt I dont know how exactly do it as I am new to mongodb.

```
customers.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$orders"},{"$lookup":{"from":"orders","localField":"_id","foreignField":"cust_id","as":"orders"}},{"$unwind":"$orders"},{"$match":{"$and":[{"cancelled_time":{"$gte":"2019-04-06 06:01:12"},"created_at":{"$lte":"2019-06-06 06:01:12"}}]}},{"$group":{"_id":{"month":{"$month":"$created_at"}},"count":{"$sum":1}}}])
```

thanks

I am new to mongodb. please help

```
customers.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$orders"},{"$lookup":{"from":"orders","localField":"_id","foreignField":"cust_id","as":"orders"}},{"$unwind":"$orders"},{"$match":{"$and":[{"cancelled_time":{"$gte":"2019-04-06 06:01:12"},"created_at":{"$lte":"2019-06-06 06:01:12"}}]}},{"$group":{"_id":{"month":{"$month":"$created_at"}},"count":{"$sum":1}}}])
```

expected result would list dialogues form both collections

Comment: please provide sample input data and expected output.

Comment: I just want to collect related dialogues from two collections. can you provide a sample query. suppose 'orders' and 'customers' are collections

Comment: Customer collection
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd8ec20e07b1f19415fe182"), 
    "name" : "5Cq5pm9jfr", 
    "country_id" : "5cca8b18e07b1f28320b18e2"
}

Order collection
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cda4e2de07b1f189b73cf32"), 
    "order_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "cust_id" : "5cd8ec20e07b1f19415fe182",    
    "rate" : NumberInt(5)
},{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cda4e2de07b1f189b73cf32"), 
    "order_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "cust_id" : "5cd8ec20e07b1f19415fe183", 
    "rate" : NumberInt(5)
},
customer's has '_id' and order's has 'cust_id' which are in relationship